# парсинг json php

Tags: php, json

Здравствуйте. У меня имеется ответ json:

```
 {"type":"album","ownerId":23,"albumId":-2,"title":"Аудиозаписи Романа Моргунова","list":[["456239056","186846466","","Как Челентано","Александр Рева ",214,0,0,"",363641547,522,"","[]","26ab13ee6da40b8189\/\/b1683e0cb3fbcf457f"],["456239055","186846466","","4. ПОРваНо Платье (Музыка Teejay)","Jah Khalib",187,0,0,"",355417090,33290,"","[]","e597f13424624dbac9\/\/3ec9d6fab5974a390b"],["456239054","186846466","","Если Чё Я Баха","Jah Khalib",172,0,0,"",355418046,522,"","[]","5c51924f0cc9c6b81c\/\/044ce2924fadcd41ca"],],"hasMore":false,"nextOffset":0,"totalCount":0,"totalCountHash":"","isComplete":true,"blocks":[]}
```

Вот так я его раскодировал:

```
$response = json_decode($content, true);
```

Но как мне получить данные из массива list(например 1 и 2 поле)??Спасибо!

Comment: я думаю вы неполучите никакой результат, на первый взгляд   (  "list":[["....   ) тут  не корректно...
вы получаете результат в $response ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По идее, должно вот так работать

```
$response = json_decode($content, true);
echo $response['list'][0][0];
```

Comment: Альтернативно используйте http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ для наглядности.

Answer (score 2):

$response - это уже сам массив, а значит обратится к его ключу надо вот так:

```
$my_value = $response[$my_key];
```

где $my_key - ваше известное значение ключа, 
а $my_value - это его значение - то что вам нужно получить.

В вашем случае

```
$my_value = $response[$my_key_1][$my_key_2];
```

где $my_key_1 - ключ массива первого уровня, а $my_key_2 - ключ второго, их так можно много подряд использовать, главное знать, что там есть этот ключ (проверить при помощи например isset($response[$my_key_1]) ).